Best way to solve overlapping sides from sculpting an edge?
In this relatively hard-surface model, edges got rather messed up during the sculpting process. Faces got lodged on the wrong side, leading to visible nastiness with backfaces clipping through.

What's the best way to approach solving this issue? The Smooth Brush doesn't seem to handle it, and I don't really want to spend a half hour adjusting vertices manually.

Missing a bit of explanation as to why you have two surfaces so close together. That said, have you tried a Shrinkwrap modifier? I believe it can be set to push any mesh inside another to the outside with a margin.

It's just a fairly acute angle. Sculpting with the Layer brush ended up pushing the vertices into this situation. I'll give the shrinkwrap modifier a shot, not sure if it'll work in this situation though.

Can you share your Blender project file? Instructions for sharing.

Not a definite fix but you can try to select the faces with select -> similar -> Normals. Then enable x-ray mode and remove all the faces that are not near to the edge (on a Mac it's selecting while holding the command key i think). This would allow you to select all the faces near one side of the edge and move them all together out of the intersection. Again, not a perfect solution but it might be a usable fix.
